Maven custom archetype - dockerfile not copied
I created a custom maven archetype. I created all the necessary directories
Inside the directory src/main/resources/archetype-resources i put all the default files and java sources I want to copy inside the generated project; between these files I have also Dockerfile and .gitignore files (not in a directory but in the root directory of the project)
So I have this structure

I created also this archetype-metadata.xml
<archetype-descriptor
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-descriptor/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-descriptor/1.1.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/archetype-descriptor-1.1.0.xsd"
        name="${artifactId}">
    <requiredProperties>
        <requiredProperty key="artifactId">
            <defaultValue>artifact.id</defaultValue>
            <validationRegex>^[a-z][a-z0-9_]*(\.[a-z0-9_]+)+[0-9a-z_]$</validationRegex>
        </requiredProperty>
        <requiredProperty key="artifactName">
            <defaultValue>artifact.name</defaultValue>
            <validationRegex>^[a-z][a-z0-9_]*(\.[a-z0-9_]+)+[0-9a-z_]$</validationRegex>
        </requiredProperty>
        <requiredProperty key="artifactDescription">
            <defaultValue>artifact.descr</defaultValue>
            <validationRegex>^[a-z][a-z0-9_]*(\.[a-z0-9_]+)+[0-9a-z_]$</validationRegex>
        </requiredProperty>
    </requiredProperties>

    <fileSets>
        <fileSet filtered="true" packaged="true" encoding="UTF-8">
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
              <include>**/*.java</include>
              <include>*.java</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet filtered="true" packaged="true" encoding="UTF-8">
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.java</include>
                <include>*.java</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet filtered="true" packaged="false" encoding="UTF-8">
            <directory>.</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>Dockerfile</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet filtered="false" packaged="false" encoding="UTF-8">
            <directory>.</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>.gitignore</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</archetype-descriptor>

When I generate the project by executing mvn archetype:generate -B ..... I don't find the Dockerfile and .gitignore files in the generated project.
Any tips on how to solve this?

remove the dot in "directory" tags when you need to include some file in project root:
<fileSet filtered="true" packaged="false" encoding="UTF-8">
     <directory></directory>
     <includes>
        <include>Dockerfile</include>
     </includes>
</fileSet>

